# Matching a value in an array (XSLT)

Tags: arrays, xslt, xslt-1.0

I will get a value from the XML file, 
e.g.

```
<WORD>Men</WORD>
```

Then, I want to create an array in XSLT 1.0,
e.g.

```
<array>
<Item>Men</Item>
<Item>Women</Item>
</array>
```

If the value from the XML file matches one of the items in the array, it will return true.
Can anyone tell me how can I do it??
Thank you!

Comment: I do not see why you would do it like this. If your data in "array" is as simple as it looks like an named template with an choose when would do far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for extension function of exsl:node-set. Have a look:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

  <xsl:param name="InputArray">
    <array>
      <Item>Men</Item>
      <Item>Women</Item>
    </array>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:param name="InputItem">
    <WORD>Men</WORD>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="exsl:node-set($InputArray)//Item[text()=exsl:node-set($InputItem)//text()]">
        <xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>No</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
  xmlns:internal="http://tempuri.org/config"
  exclude-result-prefixes="internal"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
>
  <internal:config>
    <array>
      <Item>Men</Item>
      <Item>Women</Item>
    </array>
  </internal:config>

  <xsl:variable name="config" select="document('')/*/internal:config" />

  <xsl:template match="WORD">
    <xsl:if test="$config/array/Item[. = current()]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('The current value ', ., ' was found.')" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:

- the use of a temporary namespace to store configuration in the XSLT program.
- the use of `exclude-result-prefixes` to prevent leaking the temporary namespace into the result document
- the use of `document('')` to access the contents stylesheet from within itself.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `$doc//WORD = $table//item` is true when you want it to be, and false when you want it to be, if $doc and $table are bound appropriately.